# How is a webpage controlled? by Html or javascript or xpath ?

Tags: javascript, selenium, html

I am wondering if you can help me answering a question I found to be confusing myself with.

How is a webpage controlled?

a, HTML
b, JavaScript
c, Xpath
d, CSS

Answer (score 0):

> Selenium Server receives Selenium commands from your test program,
>   interprets them, and reports back to your program the results of
>   running those tests.
>
> The RC server bundles Selenium Core and automatically injects it into
>   the browser. This occurs when your test program opens the browser
>   (using a client library API function). Selenium-Core is a JavaScript
>   program, **actually a set of JavaScript functions** which interprets and
>   executes Selenese commands using the browser’s built-in JavaScript
>   interpreter.
>
> The Server receives the Selenese commands from your test program using
>   simple HTTP GET/POST requests. This means you can use any programming
>   language that can send HTTP requests to automate Selenium tests on the
>   browser.

[Click here for more information](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/05_selenium_rc.jsp)